# Combobox AutoCompleteMode Suggest contain

Tags: c#, contains

First of I've searched allover, found the same problems, but with very different answers that i wasn't very fond of. To make it clear, I DON'T want the TextBox rebuild.
So I'm taking a shot here.

I'm having this problem that I want my combobox like AutoCompleteMode.Suggest but with a "contains" search instead of "starts with". This is my code so far like I want except contains search:

```
string displayMember = "Kund";

string sqlString = "select Kund from [Blad1$] order by Kund";

con.Open();

DataRow dataRow = table.NewRow();
dataRow[displayMember] = "";
table.Rows.InsertAt(dataRow, 0);

cB1.DataSource = table;
cB1.DisplayMember = displayMember;
cB1.SelectedIndex = 0;
cB1.Text = "";


OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlString, con);
OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read()) namesCollection.Add(dr[displayMember].ToString());

dr.Close();
con.Close();

cB1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
cB1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
cB1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namesCollection;
```

But here I have a code that doeas the search contains job by suggesting it in a dropdown, but it adds the top item to the current char in my inputbox. Like if I type "p", and it founds "Harry Potter", it looks like this "pHarry Potter". Also I can only type ONE char.

```
//join previous text and new pressed char
string name = string.Format("{0}{1}", cB1.Text, e.KeyChar.ToString()); 

DataRow[] rows = table.Select(string.Format("Kund LIKE '%{0}%'", name));

DataTable filteredTable = AllNames.Clone();
foreach (DataRow r in rows) filteredTable.ImportRow(r);
cB1.DataSource = null;
cB1.DataSource = filteredTable.DefaultView;
cB1.DisplayMember = "Kund";
cB1.DroppedDown = true;
```

I feel I'm so close, if I could somehow combine these two codes.I mean, the bottom code do find the rows I want, but doesn't act quiet like autocompletemode.suggest.
**EDIT:** I've did some progress. Although not satisfactory yet, but on the right way.
Still I dont want to use a textbox to type in. To use this method is ackward.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        con = new OleDbConnection(@"some file.xls");
        da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Kund FROM [Blad1$] ORDER BY Kund", con);

        da.Fill(AllNames);
        table = AllNames.Copy();

            DataRow dataRow = table.NewRow();
            dataRow["Kund"] = "";
            table.Rows.InsertAt(dataRow, 0);
            tempTable();
    }

public void tempTable()
    {
        try
        {
            DataRow[] rows = table.Select("Kund LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%' OR Kund LIKE ''");

            DataTable filteredTable = AllNames.Clone();
            foreach (DataRow r in rows) filteredTable.ImportRow(r);
            cB1.DataSource = null;
            cB1.DataSource = filteredTable.DefaultView;
            cB1.DisplayMember = "Kund";
            cB1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
        }
    }
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tempTable();
        cB1.DroppedDown = true;
```

Please help me.