# C# AutoComplete TextBox with 'contains' rather than 'starts with'?

Tags: c#, forms, autocomplete, textbox

In my application I need a `TextBox` with the AutoComplete feature that will suggest options based on **contain**  sub-string, rather then **start with** sub-string. Current *Visual Studio 2022* default implementation for this does only **start with** filter.

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43254621/customize-textbox-autocomplete/43254748#comment129529058_43254748) from 5 years ago, that implements this feature from scratch, both the `TextBox` and the dynamic `ListBox`. Trying to use it I found that the mouse does not work with the list.

I wanted to ask if this feature was not already solved by the C# libraries, and have to be implemented from scratch?

It sounds to me that if I could only override the **compare** function of the default implementation then this could work, but I did not find where to do this.

Will be happy if someone could direct me to the correct way to do this.

Thanks, PazO